# ¿Como puedo recuperar una imagen de un servidor web con PhP y mostrarla en un imageview en Android?

Tags: php, android, base-de-datos

os explico un poco esto.

Tengo un servidor web en la pagina https://es.000webhost.com/, en el cual tengo unos archivos php para insertar unos registros y una imagen en una base de datos, en la cual el campo imagen es del tipo longblob. Tambien tengo otro archivo php para recuperar los datos de la base de datos, que luego los muestro en una app de android, incluida la imagen. Hasta aqui todo correcto.

El problema que tengo ahora es que desde otro servidor web de la misma pagina, con su correspondiente base de datos, tengo que hacer los mismo, pero el problema es que en esta nueva base de datos el campo imagen no contiene a la imagen en si, tiene la ruta en la que esta almacenada la imagen en el servidor, y tengo que mostrar dicha imagen en una app de android. Lo hago igual que en el servidor web mencionado al principio, y los campos de texto sí que me los devuelve, pero la imagen no soy capaz de mostrarla.

Adjunto ambos archivos php para ver si me podeis dar algun tipo de ayuda, ya que llevo varios dias con esto y me está volviendo loco, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Este el php que SI me devuelve la imagen y soy capaz de mostrarla:

$json=array();

```
if(isset($_GET["documento"])){
    $documento=$_GET["documento"];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $consulta="select * from usuario where documento= '{$documento}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["documento"]=$registro['documento'];
        $result["nombre"]=$registro['nombre'];
        $result["profesion"]=$registro['profesion'];
        $result["imagen"]=base64_encode($registro['imagen']);
        $json['usuario'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["documento"]=0;
        $resultar["nombre"]='no registra';
        $resultar["profesion"]='no registra';
        $resultar["imagen"]='no registra';
        $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
    $resultar["success"]=0;
    $resultar["message"]='Ws no Retorna';
    $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Y este de aqui es el que no soy capaz de mostrar la imagen, pero si me devuelve los demas campos de la base de datos:

$json=array();

```
if(isset($_GET["cod_barras"])){
    $cod_barras=$_GET["cod_barras"];

    $consulta="select * from productos where cod_barras= '{$cod_barras}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["codigo"]=$registro['codigo'];
        $result["nombre"]=$registro['nombre'];
        $result["cantidad"]=$registro['cantidad'];

        $ruta_img = $registro["Foto"];
        $path = $ruta_img;
        $actualpath = "../uploads/fotos/$path";

        $result["Foto"]=base64_encode($actualpath);
        $json['usuario'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["codigo"]=0;
        $resultar["nombre"]='no registra';
        $resultar["cantidad"]='0';
        $resultar["Foto"]='no registra';
        $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
    $resultar["success"]=0;
    $resultar["message"]='Ws no Retorna';
    $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Te devuelve algun error o simplemente no muestra nada?

Answer (score 0):

para recuperar imagenes de un servidor mediante URL en Android, existen muchas alternativas, algunas mas faciles que otras, en este caso para la manipulación de imagenes te recomiendo usar [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
// Para cargar una imagen a un ImageView mediante URL:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("Aqui iria la ruta que te devuelve tu JSON").into(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quiere utilizar url, [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) sería tu mejor opción.

Sin embargo, si intentas pasar la imagen vía JSON codificada en Base64 tendrías que decodificarla en Android

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(imagen, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Convertir a bitmap 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

// Asignar a ImageView
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bm)
```