# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar una imagen de un servidor web con PhP y mostrarla en un imageview en Android?

Tags: php, java, android, base-de-datos, webservice

Vuelvo a ponerlo que antes la lié un poco y no podía responder a los que me aportaron alguna respuesta: 
os explico un poco esto.

Tengo un servidor web en la pagina https://es.000webhost.com/, en el cual tengo unos archivos php para insertar unos registros y una imagen en una base de datos, en la cual el campo imagen es del tipo longblob. Tambien tengo otro archivo php para recuperar los datos de la base de datos, que luego los muestro en una app de android, incluida la imagen. Hasta aqui todo correcto.

El problema que tengo ahora es que desde otro servidor web de la misma pagina, con su correspondiente base de datos, tengo que hacer los mismo, pero el problema es que en esta nueva base de datos el campo imagen no contiene a la imagen en si, tiene la ruta en la que esta almacenada la imagen en el servidor, y tengo que mostrar dicha imagen en una app de android. Lo hago igual que en el servidor web mencionado al principio, y los campos de texto sí que me los devuelve, pero la imagen no soy capaz de mostrarla.

Adjunto ambos archivos php para ver si me podeis dar algun tipo de ayuda, ya que llevo varios dias con esto y me está volviendo loco, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Este el php que SI me devuelve la imagen y soy capaz de mostrarla:

```
   $json=array();

    if(isset($_GET["documento"])){
        $documento=$_GET["documento"];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $consulta="select * from usuario where documento= '{$documento}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["documento"]=$registro['documento'];
        $result["nombre"]=$registro['nombre'];
        $result["profesion"]=$registro['profesion'];
        $result["imagen"]=base64_encode($registro['imagen']);
        $json['usuario'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["documento"]=0;
        $resultar["nombre"]='no registra';
        $resultar["profesion"]='no registra';
        $resultar["imagen"]='no registra';
        $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
    $resultar["success"]=0;
    $resultar["message"]='Ws no Retorna';
    $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Y este de aqui es el que no soy capaz de mostrar la imagen, pero si me devuelve los demas campos de la base de datos:

```
$json=array();

if(isset($_GET["cod_barras"])){
    $cod_barras=$_GET["cod_barras"];

    $consulta="select * from productos where cod_barras= '{$cod_barras}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["codigo"]=$registro['codigo'];
        $result["nombre"]=$registro['nombre'];
        $result["cantidad"]=$registro['cantidad'];

        $ruta_img = $registro["Foto"];
        $path = $ruta_img;
        $actualpath = "../uploads/fotos/$path";

        $result["Foto"]=base64_encode($actualpath);
        $json['usuario'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["codigo"]=0;
        $resultar["nombre"]='no registra';
        $resultar["cantidad"]='0';
        $resultar["Foto"]='no registra';
        $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
else{
    $resultar["success"]=0;
    $resultar["message"]='Ws no Retorna';
    $json['usuario'][]=$resultar;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: ¿Perdiste el otro usuario que veo que creaste uno nuevo y una nueva pregunta [con respecto a la anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/244005/29967)? Enviaré un reporte para que algún moderador te ayude a unificar los dos usuarios y las dos preguntas, así mantenemos el sitio un poco más ordenado. Por favor lee en la ayuda cómo funciona el sitio, cómo se editan las preguntas, etc. Y conserva tus credenciales de usuario, para cuando precises entrar de nuevo o plantear nuevas preguntas. Aquí encontrarás mucha ayuda y aprenderás buenas prácticas de programación.

Comment: En la base de datos, la columna que guarda la ruta de la foto, se llama Foto? con la F mayúscula? o es un fallo? por otro lado, $path se puede resumir a: `$path= "../uploads/fotos/".$ruta_img;`. El archivo php que muestras se encuentra en una carpeta a la misma altura que la carpeta uploads?.

Comment: Sí, el campo se llama Foto en la base de datos. El archivo php se encuentra en la carpeta public_html, mientras que las imagenes se guardan en una carpeta llamada fotos dentro de uploads.

Comment: una pregunta: puedes visualizar la imagen a traves de su ruta fisica? es decir por ejempo `localhost/proyecto/imagen.png`

Comment: No, no puedo visualizarla con su ruta fisica

Comment: Pero la carpeta uploads, que contiene la carpeta fotos, está tambien dentro de public_html, junto al archivo php? o el archivo php está dentro de una carpeta y esta carpeta dentro de public_html?